# Aurelia accessing and updating values of a public property in function

Tags: typescript, aurelia

What is the best approach to access public property from a function?

I have a scenario where when a function is executed, it should update a public property which is an object / array.

Below is my code:

**TS file**

```
formName = "support";
  formTemplate = {
    "types": [
      "text",
      "file",
      "number",
      "email"
    ],
    "support": {
      "description": "This will generate form for support request",
      "fields": [
        {
          "name": "title",
          "element": "input",
          "type": "text",
          "label": "Title",
          "placeHolder": "Provide Short Discription",
          "classes": "form-control",
          "value": ""
        },
        {
          "name": "description",
          "element": "input",
          "type": "text",
          "label": "Description",
          "placeHolder": "Provide Discription",
          "classes": "form-control",
          "value": ""
        },
        {
          "name": "email",
          "element": "input",
          "type": "text",
          "label": "Email",
          "placeHolder": "Provide email addresses",
          "classes": "form-control",
          "value": ""
        },
        {
          "name": "attachment",
          "element": "file-picker",
          "type": "file",
          "label": "Attachment",
          "placeHolder": "Insert Attachment",
          "classes": "form-control",
          "value": "test"
        }
      ]
    }
  };  

  public processForm(data) {
    this.formTemplate.support.fields.forEach(function (item, i) {
      if (item.element === 'file-picker') {
        // THIS DOESN'T WORK. NEED TO ACCESS formTemplate and update value for a property
        console.log(this.formTemplate.support.fields[i].value);
      }
    });
  }
```

So when `processForm` is executed from view on click, it should be able to access `formTemplate` object. Since `this` is local with in the function, need help on accessing `formTemplate` which is outside function scope.

Any help is really appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `function()` to [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) `=>`, as they preserve the scope in which they're declared, and therefore `this` refers to the class instead of the function.

```
public processForm(data) {
    this.formTemplate.support.fields.forEach((item, i) => {
      if (item.element === 'file-picker') {
        console.log(this.formTemplate.support.fields[i].value);
      }
    });
  }
```